# PHP TimeZone causes date() to show twice as fast as what it should

Tags: php

Running PHP 7.0.7, when I use simple date(), it outputs for example 9:00am instead of the real time that is 12:00.

The same code works just fine on my local(PHP 7.0.3), but not the server.
I have double checked the php.ini and server's time, both were correct (mysql's date function works fine on server).
TimzeZone is set on "Asia/Tehran".

Is there something that I am not aware of?

P.S. Tehran's time zone is "+4:30".

Comment: 1. Make sure your server's date and timezone are set correctly. 2. Use [`DateTime`](http://ee1.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) instead of `date()`.

> Identical to the date() function except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

Hope this helps.